# declaring a public variable causes everything to have a "name does not exist in this context" error

Tags: c#

```
    using System;

namespace GridSim
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

//error is right before declaring public. "} expected"
            public int h = 1;

            CreateWorld.Create();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a another class to create a grid in a nested for loop. the class is public. declaring a public variable ANYWHERE IN MY PROJECT yields the same result.

"} expected" before the public variable.

"The name "(insert thing here)" does not exist in this context" for literally everything after the public variable.

I want to be able to set a part of a grid to a character from anywhere in my project, but this error is preventing me from doing that.

Comment: you need to read the `C# Basics Tutorial` and focus on variables and how and where to declare them. please show a little bit more effort

Answer (score 6):

Inside a method, variables do not have access modifiers.  Remove the `public` keyword.

If this variable is supposed to be a field, move it out of the method.

> declaring a public variable ANYWHERE IN MY PROJECT yields the same result.

That's simply not true.  You can declare variables *inside methods*, and those declarations cannot contain access modifiers.  If you meant to declare this as a *field*, then that declaration can only exist at the class level, outside any methods.

Answer (score -2):

You probably meant this;

```
using System;

namespace GridSim
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {

        int h = 1;

        CreateWorld.Create();
    }
  }
}
```

You might also have meant this:

```
using System;

namespace GridSim
{
  class Program
  {
    private int _h = 1;
    public int H{
      get{ return _h; }
      set{ _h = value; }
    }

    static void Main()
    {

        CreateWorld.Create();
    }
  }
}
```

Coding standards vary but generally private variables that are class wide (declared in a class scope, not declared in a method scope) are named starting with an underscore. Public variables and properties generally start with a capital letter. We also tend not to use public variables these days; the preference being for properties. Indeed that form up there is rather archaic, declaring a private member and a get and set that access it; the shorthand `public int H{ get; set; }` is more common, with the rest of the code to make it work being filled in behind the scenes

Lastly, you have to remember that the errors you see are just the computer's best interpretation of parsing what you wrote. If you wrote something it didn't expect, then it can cause errors everywhere else; this isn't necessarily because there are errors everywhere else, simply that the first thing you wrote that was incorrect caused the compiler to treat the rest of the file incorrectly. Putting one too many } in a particular place, for example, can mean that all your code that was inside a method is suddenly inside a class instead, which will generate syntax errors all over the place

Expect these things while you're learning; it goes away as you acquire more experience and learn how the language is laid out

Comment: *Fields* (you have a field, not a variable) that are *private* typically start with an underscore.  Public fields, no.  That is very non-standard.  In fact, Microsoft officially recommends *not* using underscores in symbol names.

Comment: It's not a variable?

Comment: @Amy Fields are a type of variable.  All fields are variables.  It is a field, and that is a more descriptive term to use, but "variables" isn't incorrect.

Comment: @Amy when answering stack overflow questions I feel the hallmark of a good teacher (and generally aim to teach people to fish, not give them a fish) is one that makes attempts to explain the problem in terms the OP will understand, based on an assessment of the level they're already at. While I acknowledge that "the first step to wisdom is by calling things their proper names" I also feel that "the first step to learning frustration is to fill advice with terms the student doesn't understand". An answer may be full of technical merit but be of little practical use

Comment: I think your unsolicited advice is a bit presumptuous. You write answers how you see fit, with all the irrelevant information you desire, and I'll write answers as I see fit.